# opencart 3 Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Tags: php, opencart, opencart3.x

**opencart v 3.0.3.3**

**php v 7.4**

на странице оформления заказа, рядом со способами оплаты **(payment_method)** получаю ошибку

Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/.../public_html/**catalog/model/extension/payment/cod.php** on ***line 6***

6 строка в файле это

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM "
. DB_PREFIX . "zone_to_geo_zone WHERE geo_zone_id = '"
. (int)$this->config->get('payment_cod_geo_zone_id')
. "' AND country_id = '" . (int)$address['country_id']
. "' AND (zone_id = '" . (int)$address['zone_id'] . "'
OR zone_id = '0')");
```

Никак не пойму что за ошибка, кто знает?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674903/trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-bool-in-php-7-4

Comment: @splash58 не смог разобраться, можете дать более развернутый ответ?